# Working with Microsoft Report Viewer on Azure Functions

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-functions, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm trying to use RDLC on an Azure Function but when locally works all fine, when deployed on Azure I have errors on loading DLLs. One time I have errors on ReportViewer.Common, another time error on SqlServer.Types, there are many NuGet packages but I'm confused about what is correct to install.

If anyone has a similar situation working please share packages and versions used because I googled but an answer to this problem seems not exist.

(I know that locally works fine because it loads DLLs from GAC, and I also verified that on a server in the BIN folder exist DLLs that seems to not exist)

thanks to all

**Update of the situation 04/03/2020:**

My Azure Function is the V1 version, I can now say that with ReportViewer.Common 12.0 deployed on Azure **works** with a simple report with poor content, just some labels, so the problem is not that RDLC cannot run on Azure Function but that there is something in the content of my structured report (i think Expressions) that cause a call to certain DLL that cause the error.

My Azure Function runs on Standard App Service plan so sandbox wouldn't be the problem...I think.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not yet, i'm asking support to Microsoft Specialists

Comment: any updates about this, did you find a resolution ?

Comment: As per my answer below, it could very well be that the extended functionality you are referring to are dependent on dll’s that are not being resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you just need to add

```
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Report.Viewer" Version="11.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to your "function.proj" of your azure function(if you use azure function v2).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Report Viewer most likely makes use of GDI+ / System.Drawing, that is blocked on certain Microsoft Azure services as it is a security vulnerability (could allow for remote code execution).

My understanding is that on higher priced tiers, they are more permissive and will only block certain functions from executing.

You problem might also relate to the use of shared libraries, such as for graphics or cryptography.

For a list of allowed functions, see here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Comment: i know this limitations but as i said this report worked for me before using some expression formula inside the report. Also i can say that the the App Service Plan is Standard Plan so i think not limited

Comment: Did you include any graphs on your report?

Comment: no, only some expression formula in some cells of a table

Comment: Do any of those expressions perhaps contain embedded custom code or vbscript functions, as per this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are missing dll's on your remote deployment, that is installed on your local machine's GAC.  Specifically, ensure that your have referenced `Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll` and that you have set copylocal to true for all referenced dll's.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx